# flutter google map marker for current position

Tags: flutter, marker

How could I have goolge map's style marker for current location , it can even show the direction of current position ?

this is my code, the marker style of my code is just a pin, i want
to have google map's marker style even to show the direction of current position .

```
 _markerSet.add(
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('current_Postion'),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Current Position'),
      position: _userCurrentPositionLatLng,
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
        BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen,
      ),
    ),
```

This is how my marker looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FASvF.png)

This is the google marker which i want to have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbwzg.png)

Any hints for suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**
Set `myLocationEnabled: true,` on the `GoogleMap` widget. It will automatically take care of that.

*This works for a custom marker:*
You cannot directly get the location from Google Map.
You can use this [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package to get the users location (latitude and longitude) and then add the marker accordingly to the map.